# How to display a component only after removing another in structural directives?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a skeleton directive. (code example below)

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appSkeleton]',
})
export class SkeletonDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input('appSkeleton') isLoading: boolean;
    @Input('appSkeletonSkeletonTemplate') skeletonTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.isLoading) {
            this.viewContainer.clear();

            if (changes.isLoading.currentValue) {
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.skeletonTemplate);
            } else {
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is needed to implement the skeleton loader in the application. (it works like this)

```html
 <app-some-component *appSkeleton="loading; skeletonTemplate:someComponentSkeleton"></app-some-component>
```

But there is a problem that all the life cycle hooks of the component on which the directive is called are triggered at the moment when there are two components in the DOM - the main and the skeleton. This leads to problems (for example, if there is ngAfterViewInit)

Is it possible to somehow make the component template appear only after the skeleton has definitely removed from the DOM ?

I also tried wrapping `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);` in `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)`, this helps to solve the problem, but it leads to the fact that there is a lag when the DOM does not contain both the skeleton and my component ( a blank screen appears for a while and this does not suit me)

Comment: Try use the "Input" as a "getter": `@Input('appSkeleton') set isLoading(value){..your code here..}`

Comment: @Eliseo, Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't help(